# Sudo ln not creating the link

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

If I try and create a link without sudo in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` it fails with a permission denied.

When I try and do it with sudo a file is created but it is not a link.

Any ideas?

The exact command I am running from sites-enabled is `ln ../sites-available/newsite newsite`

The file I am linking to is owned by me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ln` creates hard links by default. Pass `-s`.